# Express js error 404 page intercepts with static files

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I used the code below to handle error 404 but it is intercepting with my static files.
Here are my static file structure

```
-public
   -images [folder]
    -uploaded [folder]
     -image.png
```

---

```
app.use(express.static('public'));

app.use(function(req, res) {
        res.status(400);
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/views/404.html'));
});

app.get("/images", (req, res) => {
    var path = "public/images/uploaded/";
    var images = "";
    fs.readdir(path, function(err, items) {
        images = items;
        res.json({ images });
    });
});
```

The '/images' route returns error 404. How can I correct this?

Comment: Is the path correct?

Comment: Can you share the request details(maybe the cURL)? are you sure you are making a GET request?

Comment: Ye it is @Senal

Answer (score 2):

Move the error handler function to be the bottom. i.e. it should come after all the other route definitions.